# That noise in old vinyls or rather shellac plates

Tags: single-word-requests, music

How would you call the typical background noise in old phonograph records?

How would you call a record that sounds like that?

For an example from YouTube: [Billie Holiday, You better go now, 1947](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfSkGdhD8Jo)

Comment: That recording is [**scratchy**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/scratchy) see **1.2** entry.

Comment: Either, static, hiss, ticks, clicks, pops depending on the sound.  Although hiss is more appropriate for tapes than records.

Comment: A general term might be 'surface noise'.